# No such a Instance Field in custom array list <Previewdata>...?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, android-custom-view

How to fix with issue the issue **No such a Instance Field** for custom array list.

I need your help for fix the issue **I am parsing the data from web API**. the api providing the accurate data and parsing of json is also done.

```
  private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, ArrayList<PreviewData>> {
        public ArrayList<PreviewData> Datalist = new ArrayList<PreviewData>() ;
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;
        Constant constant = new Constant();
        Context context;
        public DownloadFilesTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<PreviewData> doInBackground(Void... params) {

           NOTE :please note String id,name and email is just dummy items to explain the question;

          /*     Example   */

          for(int i=0;i<jsonobj.length();i++){

           String id =jsonobj.get("id");

           String name =jsonobj.get("name");

           String Email =jsonobj.get("Email");

           PreviewData tempdata = new PreviewData(id, name, Email);    /* data is coming in tempdata list */

           Datalist.add(tempdata);     /* what when i want to add this data in Datalist then it show no such a instance field*/

           }
           return countryList;
        }

       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<PreviewData> result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
           adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.view_all_campaign_row, Datalist);

           /* Here i want to add the data  in adapter */

           listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.campaign_list_view);
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
           nDialog.dismiss();
           Log.i("PostEx",Datalist.toString());
        }  
    }
```

Comment: What does you JSON look like?

Comment: json file is tooo long i canot post here  i write note : data parsing is done.

json parsing provide my saprate values that i need.

so there no need to explain json file

Comment: Try restarting your Android Studio or Rebuild the Project